# how can i explore a GraphQL api endpoint using localhost server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Hello i have a **GraphQL** API endpoint that i ran locally using "yarn start", I am supposed to use this **API** in my react app but i do not know how to explore the API so i can use it in my react app, I have already tried to explore it in postman but i still cant see what it contains of.

Answer (score 0):

If your API is well set up, you should be able to query it with Postman: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/graphql/

To use queries and mutations in react I suggest you to use the [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/).

Answer (score 0):

GraphiQL is an interactive tool for exploring GraphQL APIs. See https://github.com/graphql/graphiql for more.